# Ошибка потеря соединения с Интернетом на сайте Laravel php ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

Tags: php, laravel

Есть одинаковая проблема на 2х сайтах на фреймворке Laravel.

Ошибка в потери соединения с интернетом , воспроизводится не постоянно и на разных устройствах с разной ОС (mac/Chrome, HP/Ubuntu ...).

После ухода компютера в сон и его отключения и дальнейшего включения - в браузере, где открыты множество вкладок - но именно на этих двух сайтах показана ошибка потери соединения  - ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED .   (с остальными открытыми вкладками все в порядке)

После обновления страницы, все в порядке. Но эта пропажа соединения является проблемой

Используется:
laravel framework: 5.8 php: 7.1

Возможно у кого то была такая проблема или есть идеи где искать причину?

Comment: При чём здесь PHP или Laravel? Это ошибка браузера.

Comment: Вряд ли виноват браузер, так как ошибка происходит только на двух сайтах из 15 открытых вкладок. 
А также наблюдается у разных пользователей на разных устройствах с разными браузерами.